# NextJS/Vercel not serving .mp4 file in public folder in production

Tags: next.js, vercel, git-lfs

I have a video.mp4 file in my public folder in a NextJS app. When running Next locally (npm run dev) I can reach the file by typing localhost:3000/video.mp4 but once I push to Vercel mydomain.com/video.mp4 doesn't work. I have used Git LFS to push the video file because it was over 100mbs. I have other static files in my public folder such as images and icons and these work perfectly well in both development and production environments.

I have no clue what to do. Any ideas?

Comment: You can check what files are present on your deployment by looking at the Source tab, and output. https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/edge-network/directory-listing

Comment: @Mentlegen that's only if no index file is present and I do have an index file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vercel currently does not support Git LFS. We recommend hosting that video asset elsewhere.

https://vercel.com/support/articles/best-practices-for-hosting-videos-on-vercel-nextjs-mp4-gif

Comment: Is this same for html files too. I can't serve HTML files from public folder

Comment: As this is the only point of reference I found: Is this still the case and is there some kind documentation  regarding LFS? I got some large JSON files I need to work with.